# Boostrap 4: Modal won't show on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add a modal to my app. I make it so that once my page is loaded, it will show( does not require button) for test purpose.
I have `"bootstrap": "^4.1.3"` as my dependency.

On my CSS, i make it so that the display is block:

```
.modal{
  display: block
}

.modal-content{
  display: block
}
```

In my react app, I import it and use it as follow:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <header className="App-header">
                  Code Authentication
                </header>

                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                      {this.getPhoneList()}
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                      {this.getMethodList()}
                  </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.VerifyCode()}>
                  VERIFY CODE
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I copied the modal code from boostrap's document and modified a little bit so it works for my test purpose. I also tried many different code, but none of the modal worked.

What I have tried: I have read many of Posts related to this issues on Stack. Many of them were simply due to the fact that the OP did not include certain file or the attribute of display is not set to show. In my case, i am neither.

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Where's the code to open the modal?

Comment: @Zim i made it so  that the modal will just show witout a button's invoke. Because I m trying to do a modal-like UI, so I am just simply putting my elements in the modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal is meant to be shown with a trigger which adds `modal-open` to the body and `show` to the modal. To make the modal show remove `fade`, and add the `d-block` class which will force the modal to display.

```
<div className="modal d-block" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
...
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/r47k4BlDKA

Comment: thank you! Just one more questions: Is it good practice to use modal for modal-like UI? I will later have to change the content in the modal by button, it seems like a complicated thing to implement in react. I feel i am having a wrong approach

Comment: I'm not sure that's kind of a subjective question, but normally the modal is used as a modal and that's it.

Comment: I see. Isn't d block the same as display: block ? Why does setting modal's display to block won't work , but d block works?

Comment: Setting the `.modal` to display:block should work also.

Comment: I had it( see my question), it does not work. Only d-block worked.

Comment: It does work: https://www.codeply.com/go/GHOg12b8m2 ... OFC using `fade` too will hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `.fade` class has the attribute `opacity: 0;` your CSS should be overriding this with `opacity: 1;`